# axios set headers content-type not working in request headers in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

```
 let input = {
    'email': email,
    'password': password
    };

    axios({        
        method:'POST',
        url: URL,
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
         },
        data: input
    }).then(function (response){
        console.log(response);

    })
    .catch(function (error) {

    });
```

I try to request API with axios using method post. It not seen set request headers content-type,but if I using jquery ajax it ok.

[image: image of headers]

Comment: have you tried like that:  `headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
         },`?

Comment: yeah... I tried like you wrote, but it not work.

Comment: I am having this issue as well. Any solutions?

Comment: Actually I’m having the same issue,I think this is due to cors policy. If you watch the request header it includes below:{ ‘ Access-Control-Request-Header’: content-type} is preventing to send our content-type request header.One temporary fix is to disable the browser cors policy. In safari this can by turn off by clicking disable cross origin in develop mode.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `charset=utf-8` is not set along with headers.

`Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8` designates the content to be in JSON format, encoded in the UTF-8 character encoding. Designating the encoding is somewhat redundant for JSON, since the default (only?) encoding for JSON is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

its a bug in axios -.- there are multiple issues for this Problem.

I can show you my solution. I hope it's working for you, too.

```js
import qs from 'qs'
let input = qs.stringify {
'email': email,
'password': password
});

axios
  .post(URL, input)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.headers)
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Framework provides first class support for CORS. CORS must be processed before Spring Security because the pre-flight request will not contain any cookies (i.e. the JSESSIONID). If the request does not contain any cookies and Spring Security is first, the request will determine the user is not authenticated (since there are no cookies in the request) and reject it.

The easiest way to ensure that CORS is handled first is to use the CorsFilter. Users can integrate the CorsFilter with Spring Security by providing a CorsConfigurationSource using the following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
      // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
      .cors().and()
      ...
 }

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
  CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
  configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
  configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
  configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
  UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
  UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
  source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
  return source;
 }
}
```